# Hibernate envers - get audited properties of entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Is there an easy (built-in) way to get all envers-audited properties for an entity? e.g.

```
public class SomeClass {
    @Audited
    private String auditedString;

    private String otherString;
    // getter, setter
}
```

I'd like to know if there is some utility function in envers which returns an array of @Audited properties (e.g. [auditedString]) for a given class or instance.

Thank you!

Maria

Comment: Maria, Are you looking for method to get audited data?

Comment: Hi! no, just the names of the audited properties. Maybe there is some built-in function I didn't find.

Comment: I had similar need, to list field names of all *modified* properties and I had to do it myself. But listing field names with `@Audited` annotation is easy with Java reflection. Just keep in mind that `@Audited` can be specified on the class itself.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I know that it can be done by reflection, but I didn't want to reinvent the wheel and was wondering if envers was already providing something in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following would work, but understand that the code is accessing Envers internals and isn't guaranteed to be portable across releases.

```
// Get the Envers Service
final EnversService enversService = session.getSessionFactory()
        .getServiceRegistry()
        .getService( EnversService.class );

// Get the entity configuration
EntityConfiguration entityCfg = enversService.getEntityConfigurations()
        .get( auditEntityName );

// Set that contains the properties associated with the audited entity.
Set<PropertyData> properties = entityCfg.getPropertyMapper()
        .getProperties()
        .keySet();
```